# Как реализовать чат без сервера?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу создать простой консольный чат в одной сети Wi-Fi без подключения к интернету. Как это можно сделать? Что нужно загуглить?

Comment: Вам нужно загуглить "клиент-серверный чат на python"

Comment: *чат в одной сети Wi-Fi без подключения к интернету* Как правило, клиенты в WiFi-сегменте работают в изолированном режиме - т.е. трафик между ними не передаётся.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/151623/

Answer (score 1):

Консольный локальный чат можно реализовать без сервера, сокетов и других библиотек. Это будет достаточно костыльный чат, но тем не менее работать будет как надо)

**Как один из вариантов, вам понадобятся:**

1. Файл синхронизации сообщений, в котором всегда хранится последнее отправленное в чат сообщение
2. Файл с историей сообщений, в который дописывается каждое новое сообщение и весь файл подгружается при запуске чата
3. Главный файл чата - просто подгружает историю чата и отображает новые сообщения
4. Консоль отправки сообщений - отдельное окно, в котором сначала вводится ник, с которым пользователь зайдет в чат, а затем оттуда отправляются последующие сообщения

Конечно, такой чат не позволит синхронизировать пользователей, т.е. в один чат одновременно сможет зайти хоть 10 человек с одинаковым ником и с одного компа. (хотя при желании и эту проблему можно решить)

---

**Примерный алгоритм:**

**Главный файл чата:** при первом запуске подгружает весь текст из файла с историей чата. Если текст в файле с последним сообщением изменился, значит было отправлено новое сообщение. Следовательно, при изменении текста в файле с последним сообщением - отображаем новое сообщение.

**Консоль отправки:** запрашивает логин для входа, после ввода в файл с последним сообщением записывается строка о том что *такой-то пользователь заходит в чат* и соответственно отображается в чате. Затем в цикле консоль запрашивает ввод через `input('Сообщение>')` и при каждом вводе отправляет текст в файл с последним сообщением. Выход из чата можно реализовать просто через закрытие окна консоли. Обработать это закрытие можно с помощью библиотеки `win32api`. То есть, при закрытии окна консоли отправки сообщений, если пользователь вводил ник и "авторизовался" в чате, будет выведено сообщение о том, что он покинул чат.

---

Разумеется, можно попытаться совместить главное окно и консоль отправки в одно окно, но я предложил самый простой вариант. Также подключив какую-нибудь шифрующую библиотеку (либо написать свой скрипт), можно шифровать данные, например, в файле истории.

Надеюсь вам поможет моя идея, удачи :)

Comment: А где будет храниться главный файл чата при отсутствии сервера? Как понимаю любой комп в сети может произвольно быть офлайн.

Comment: Если пк не находится в локальной сети, то он в любом случае не сможет получить доступ к главному файлу

Comment: А если ПК с главным файлом офлайн, вопрос про такой случай. Как я понял есть только клиенты эпизодически появляющиеся в сети.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно:

1. Сканировать все ip локальной сети.
2. Пройтись по активным ip опросить на запуск клиента.
3. Составить список юзеров на основе пункта 2.
4. Все можно слать сообщения.

Остается определиться с типом чата тет-а-тет или широковещательная рассылка всем пользователям.

Историю можно хранить у каждого клиенты в txt с временными маркерами и при коннекте синхронизировать или забить на нее и получать только текущие сообщения.
И тд. и тп. алгоритм можно улучшать разными фичами очень долго зависит от желания замарочиться.